# Bulk delete records from post uninstall script

Tags: managed-package, bulk-delete, uninstall

I'm writing a post-uninstall script for a managed package that will delete a set of records that are no longer used. This works fine at the moment but I want to make it capable of deleting very large numbers of records if necessary, higher than the limits imposed by Salesforce for a single transaction. Normally I'd write a batch class to handle a bulk delete like this but post-uninstall scripts don't allow this. Is there any way around this, or any other way of bulk deleting 100,000+ records from a post uninstall script?

Comment: What object are you trying to delete from? Is it a standard object or a custom object from the managed package?

Comment: It's a custom object but not from the package being uninstalled.

Comment: Were I the database administrator, I would be *very concerned* about a managed package deleting 100,000 records from an object other than its own upon install. Why not build a Visualforce or Lightning page to allow the user to initiate the delete, using a batch class.

Comment: That is our backup plan but I'd like it to be automated. To clarify, the records are deleted after UNinstall, not install, and were only created as a result of the package being installed in the first place.

Comment: Apologies, I misread that it's upon uninstall. I'd still consider it worrying functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Just schedule a batch to do the hard delete from within your post install script. Be aware though that this should have the without sharing keyword. Otherwise the post install script will fail.